# Look up the serviceName needed for Google Service Management API using the id or name returned from Google Discovery API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-apis-explorer

We use Google Discovery API to get and explore the list of Google APIs.

Google also provides Service Management APIs, in which one can enable a service for a project, given the serviceName:

POST https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/{serviceName}:enable

However from Google Discovery API, this serviceName is not surfaced anywhere.  For example, for BigQuery, the following is returned from Discovery API:

```
    {
    "kind":"discovery#directoryItem",
    "id":"bigquery:v2",
    "name":"bigquery",
    "version":"v2",
    "title":"BigQuery API",
    "description":"A data platform for customers to create, manage, share and query data.",
    "discoveryRestUrl":"https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest",
    "discoveryLink":"./apis/bigquery/v2/rest",
    "icons":{
    "x16":"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/search-16.gif",
    "x32":"https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/search-32.gif"
    }

,
"documentationLink":"https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/",
"preferred":true
}
```

But the serviceName "bigquery-json.googleapis.com" that is needed for Service Management API in order to enable it is not found anywhere from the response from Discovery API.

Does anyone know where I can programmatically look up the serviceName needed for Service Management API using the id or name returned from Discovery API?

Thank you.